# Solr query- How to remove all special-characters logical interpretation?

Tags: solr, special-characters

This is slightly different than remove all special character from input String. I just want them as-it-is. For example:

Query: Haha AND LaLa would be tokenized as

```
1. Haha
2. And
3. LaLa
```

not

```
1. Haha
2. LaLa
```

and with the same logic, a single input of special character such as:

```
`! , . : ; OR NOT < >`
```

would be...themselves (Not logical constructor and the query would return result if in database there are names like that exist)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **field or raw query parser** they search for the query string that you have typed without any analysis or transformation.

```
q = {!field f='title'} Haha AND LaLa
```

[**Debug-Response**]

```
<lst name="debug">
<str name="rawquerystring">{!field f='title'}Haha AND LaLa</str>
<str name="querystring">{!field f='title'}Haha AND LaLa</str>
<str name="parsedquery">title:Haha AND LaLa</str>
<str name="parsedquery_toString">title:Haha AND LaLa</str>
<str name="QParser"/>
</lst>
```

As you can see from the response Solr Looking for the document which contains "Haha AND LaLa". **Field query parser** treats "AND" as search keyword not as Logical operator.

Comment: This is useful but is about the query side. The question was more about the index side. Could you update the answer to provide both aspects to make it generally useful.